# iTunes Store Doesn't Recognize iTunes Library

Tags: itunes, icloud, music, itunes-match, itunes-store

About two weeks ago, iTunes stopped recognizing my iTunes library. I get this message when I go to either **File** → **Library** → **Update iCloud Music Library** or **Update Genius**:

[image: iTunes Store Doesn’t Recognize iTunes Library]

There is no such option under **File** → **Library**. I tried disabling *Genius Recommendations* under my account, then turning them back on, but with no success. What is causing this and how can I fix it?

I have iTunes Match, but not Apple Music, if that matters.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Logging out of my iTunes account and logging back in did the trick.

- **Account** → **Sign Out**
- **iTunes** → **Quit iTunes**
- Wait a bit, relaunch iTunes
- **Account** → **Sign In**
- **iTunes** → **Preferences** → **General** → *uncheck* `iCloud Music Library`
- Click OK, wait a bit
- **iTunes** → **Preferences** → **General** → *check* `iCloud Music Library`

iTunes should immediately start updating your **iCloud Music Library**. Once that’s done, everything should be working correctly.

Comment: Steps 1-3 aren't always necessary (and are very, very slow and painful if you have a large library).  You can just 1. Uncheck "iCloud Music Library", 2. File > Library > Turn off Genius, 3. wait a few minutes, 4. turn Genius back on, 5. turn iCloud Library back on.  Took me <5min for a 250gb library.

Comment: @NickSweeting thank you, your suggestion of turning on Genius separately before turning on iCloud is the only thing that worked for me.